# Errors Handling in WCF - how to pass the error to client as well as remain the channel in the "Open" state

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling

I want to realize the schema, under which all the application-defined errors in my WCF service will be delivered to the clients, but the communication channel must remain in the `Open` state.

At the current point the first task is realized by means of `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true`, but after the first exception the communication channel state moves from `Open` to `Fault`. How can I prevent such a behaviour (the corruption of the communication channel after the first exception in the service code)?

Comment: You need to handle any errors and not let them go unhandled - unhandled exceptions will fault the channel (as you've discovered).  You can implement IErrorHandler as global exception catcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faulted channel can't be closed and can't be used again. A faulted channel must be **aborted** by calling `Abort()` Method. Also instead of using `"IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true"`, it would be better to throw a [`FaultExceptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception(v=vs.110).aspx). And it is also recommended that you use the [`FaultContractAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to design your services to return strongly-typed **SOAP** faults.